# Open a Closed Form VBA Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

If there a way to re-open a form that is being closed without Access overloading?

I've got a Modal Form that I want the user to fill out and don't want them to leave that screen until that data is filled.

I've tried just re-opening the form that they're trying to close, but it overloads Access and wont let me do anything at all after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel the closing of the form by setting `Cancel = True` in the `OnUnload` event.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    If Not CheckAllDataIsFilled() And Not bCancelButtonClicked Then
        MsgBox "Please fill out all data.", vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

But you should always provide a way of canceling the form, or users will get very upset with you, and they won't refrain from killing Access via Task Manager if there is no other way.

Comment: Does this work on the close button? Maybe I should have clarified that...

Comment: Yes, it does. And on Alt+F4 and `Docmd.Close` etc.